# PostgresSQL not successfully doing a search+bind authentication

Tags: active-directory, ldap, authentication, postgresql

I'm attempting to configure my Postgresql server 12.6 [Ubuntu 20.04 build] to do authenticated LDAP user authentication against my 2012 Active Directory tree via LDAP. I've set up my pg_hba.conf file here is my most recent attempt. I've also tried the ldapserver style setup and both get the same error results.

`host all all all ldap ldapurl="ldap://stc.int:389/dc=stc,dc=int?sAMAccountName" ldapbinddn="CN=PostgreSQL Service Account,OU=Service Accounts,DC=stc,DC=int" ldapbindpasswd="<scrubed>"`

When I try to log in, I get the following errors on the server:

```
2021-05-26 12:47:00.008 UTC [2767782] btyger-admin@btyger-admin LOG:  could not search LDAP for filter "(sAMAccountName=btyger-admin)" on server "stc.int": Operations error
2021-05-26 12:47:00.008 UTC [2767782] btyger-admin@btyger-admin DETAIL:  LDAP diagnostics: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0907E9, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580
2021-05-26 12:47:00.008 UTC [2767782] btyger-admin@btyger-admin FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "btyger-admin"
2021-05-26 12:47:00.008 UTC [2767782] btyger-admin@btyger-admin DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 106: "host all all all ldap ldapurl="ldap://stc.int:389/dc=stc,dc=int?sAMAccountName" ldapbinddn="CN=PostgreSQL Service Account,OU=Service Accounts,DC=stc,DC=int" ldapbindpasswd="<scrubed>""
```

I know that AD error happens when an LDAP client tries to do an unauthenticated search. I've verified the credentials with a ldapsearch command from the same machine and the parameter/credentials verify correctly.

Am I missing something here or am I seeing a bug?

Comment: have you verified both the bind account credentials as the user credentials?

Answer (score 0):

longshot: set the scope to sub. Standard in this configuration is base.

From: [the posgres ldap docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auth-ldap.html)

ldapurl
An RFC 4516 LDAP URL. This is an alternative way to write some of the other LDAP options in a more compact and standard form. The format is

ldap[s]://host[:port]/basedn[?[attribute][?[scope][?[filter]]]]

scope must be one of base, one, sub, typically the last. (The default is base, which is normally not useful in this application.) attribute can nominate a single attribute, in which case it is used as a value for ldapsearchattribute. If attribute is empty then filter can be used as a value for ldapsearchfilter."

Comment: I did try that already. It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It was a problem with Active Directory LDAP policies.

- One policy said I couldn't search without an authenticated user.
- Another said I wasn't allowed to bind over an unsecured LDAP.
- Thought I was using a different TLS certificate

So when I tried to bind as the service account over LDAPS, I was hitting the wrong cert error. When I tried to bind over unsecured LDAP, I was the not allowed to bind over unsecured LDAP.